# WooCommerce: merge upsells and cross-sells

Tags: woocommerce

I wonder if it's possible to **programmatically** add all cross-sell products as upsells too (or the other way around)? The reason I want to do this is that I want to show the same products as both cross-sells and upsells without having to add them manually twice.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way for how to replace a product's upsells with the cross-sells instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_upsell_ids', 'custom_upsell_ids', 20, 2 );
function custom_upsell_ids( $upsell_ids, $product ) {
    return $product->get_cross_sell_ids();
}
```